# Reading a sequence of handwritten numbers using Deep Networks with MNIST Data in R - Part1

Tags: r, ocr, mnist

Is it possible to read a sequence of numbers using Deep Networks trained with MNIST Data? For example the following number that I have written in Windows Paint:
[image]

Comment: It is possible, there are many tutorials online, have you tried any? Try some, lets us know if you get stuck: https://rpubs.com/Argaadya/nn-mnist or https://github.com/anishsingh20/Deep-Learning-in-R-using-Keras-and-Tensorflow- etc ...

Comment: Dear friend, I have run the R code successfully from here: https://github.com/anishsingh20/Deep-Learning-in-R-using-Keras-and-Tensorflow-/blob/master/deepNeuralNet.R

However, I don’t know how I can input my handwriting? I mean how can this program can recognise my handwriting (the figure above). Which code should I use?

Comment: @zx8754
Can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195228/reading-handwritten-numbers-using-deep-networks-with-mnist-data-in-r-part3